# Selenium Test cases for UI look

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, selenium2, uiautomation

I have a `test case`, where I need to verify:

1. a user selects any of the *options*.
2. the *text* is not going out of the *layout* and *displays* complete
   readability to the user.

As a result, the `UI` look and feel **user-friendly** and does not go off the layout.

Any idea to make this *test*?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Why are you testing content? You usually do not want to use automation to test content because it changes all the time. Is there a history of this product where text/copy breaks the layout? Have you thought about using a visual test tool like Percy?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem the solution I found is to check the style of the content using methods like (getCssValue and getLocation). So, we can check the style of the element is it stable or not if not we need to make a manual test

Answer (score 0):

We need more details for your question.

Let's start from Selenium WebDriver.
This framework was developed to create robust, browser-based regression functional automation suites and tests, scale and distribute scripts  across most modern web browsers.

So, with WebDriver actually you can automate the next scenario:

1. Open required browser.
2. Navigate to required page.
3. Interact with page (click or select some elements).
4. Verify that action was performed
5. Take screenshot of the page.
6. Save screenshot with test run results.
7. Manually verify the text/UI looks good (this step can't be automated with WebDriver).

If you need to do automated testing for UI you should remember, that UI testing is centered around two main things:

1. checking how the application handles user actions carried out using the keyboard, mouse, and other input devices.
2. checking whether visual elements are displayed and working
   correctly.

For that purpose you could use special UI automation frameworks (I had experience only with Sikuli UI automation framework). For more details check [here](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/best-gui-testing-tools/#15_Sikuli_UI_automation_framework).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can write the test cases for UI look using Selenium:

1. Verify Option Selection:

- First, you need to select an option from the dropdown or list of options.
- You can use the `select_by_visible_text` or `select_by_index` method from the Select class of the selenium library.
- Verify the selected option matches the expected option.
- Verify Text Readability.

2. You need to locate the span, label, or any other element that displays the text.

- Get the size and position of the element using the size and location methods.
- Verify the text fits within the bounds of the element and does not overflow.
- You can also verify the font size, color, and any other styles to ensure the text is readable.

Note: For these test cases, you may need to use the selenium WebDriver's methods for inspecting element properties, such as `find_element_by_xpath`, `find_element_by_css_selector`, and `get_attribute`.

Answer (score -1):

I have used *UI automation frameworks* that may get a **diff** between the screens.
But there are no good approaches to check your case with typical *automation tools*.